# Insert Data Using Web API in asp.net

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am a beginner in asp.net & i am stuck in a problem facing in inserting data using web API without using Entity Framework. I need to store data from mobile app in my database using API. The data will come in JSON format from mobile device & need to insert in database.
Is HttpPost is used for this? if yes then how it would be done?
Please help me on this...

**EDIT**
I use this code for getting data from database...

**HttpGet**

```
public HttpResponseMessage aisleshelf(string ApiKey, string storeId = "")
{
    headerParameter objheaderParameter = new headerParameter();
    string Url = Convert.ToString(Request.RequestUri);
    Url = Url.Replace("'", "''");
    DBClass objDbclass = new DBClass();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string CustomerId = null, Description = null, Aisle = null;
    Boolean UStatus = true;
    Boolean ErrorStatus = false;
    List<Aisle> objlistAisle = new List<Aisle>();
    List<AisleShelf> objlistAisleShelf = new List<Models.AisleShelf>();
    List<Aislelist> objlistAislelist = new List<Aislelist>();
    Aislelist objAislelist = new Aislelist();
    aisleshelfitem objaisleshelfitem = new aisleshelfitem();
    int Code;
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    UserValid(ApiKey, Url, out UStatus, out  CustomerId, out Code, out Description, UserIpAddress);
    if (UStatus)
    {
        ds = objDbclass.AisleShelf(ApiKey, Url, out ErrorStatus, UserIpAddress, storeId);
        // This will forward to my class where i wrtir a method to get data using stored procedure.
    }
```

i need to create an apicontroller to insert data.

see this article where data is inserted in database via webmethod.
http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2014/11/jquery-ajax-json-example-in-aspnet-to.html

now in my case user send data via mobile to call my api to insert his record in database.

Comment: How much basic knowledge do you have? How would in your world a HttpPost magically end up in a database? You throw terms around for technologies that you seem to have zero understanding about.

Comment: Have you tried anything if yes please share the code , It is difficult to address your specific issue with out knowing more details. You have to use HTTP POST itself for creating new resource.

Answer (score 0):

In controller use something like this

```
dynamic json = JValue.Parse(this.HttpContext.Request.Params[0]);
JToken jt = json.postRequest;
```

in view, i.e. web page I use jQuery ajax

```
$.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url: '/Template/DataGridList',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: JSON.stringify({postRequest:postRequest}),
       success: function (data) {
          $dfd.resolve(data);
       },
       error: function () {
          $dfd.reject();
       }
 });
```

Comment: And how can he save this into the db?

Comment: As I understand, he can't get data first of all. JToken has dynamic object, that has his data. I don't know what data he is sending. I don't know what database he uses.